# window.onload doesn't work with Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to put google chart into window.onload, but it doesn't show anything instead, in the status bar, it shows 'Transferring data from www.google.com...' I know if we put the code outside window.onload it will surely work, but I want to put in window.onload. Any suggestions? thanks

Here is my code

[image]

Comment: Not a real answer, but its generally a better practice to put your scripts tags just prior to the closing body tag. Just a pet peeve, and it does fix this type of error in SOME instances

Comment: Are you sure the code inside window.onload is executing? Put a debug statement in there. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm very sure that the code inside window.onload is executing. It gives the alert. You can try.

Comment: I think window.onload is conflict with the google onload callback (setOnLoadCallback())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`drawChart` callback should be invoked when API would be loaded, for that you need to define `callback` key in third argument of `google.load` function:

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {
  window.onload = function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
      packages:['corechart'],
      callback: drawChart
    });

    function drawChart() {
      console.log('drawChart');
    }
  };
})(window, window.document);
```

Comment: u have saved my life. Thank you. I want to give you 1000 votes up, but stackoverflow allows only 1. Thanks again.

Comment: Upping this answer because I was stumped for ages on why my chart wouldn't draw. I had set the callback via 'google.setOnLoadCallback(...)' but for some reason the callback was never getting triggered. Setting the callback within google.load(..) as you outlined did the trick. Thanks!